# question about fast/slow muscle twitch fibers

Tags: genetics

Here are my questions (I have several)

1) Are the fast twitch muscle fibers dominant or recessive as opposed to the slow?

2) Are people of mixed race/greatest genetic diversity in their background, tend to be the best athletes and the healthiest in general?

Allow me to clarify the first point:  Obviously no one in the world is either 100% fast twitch or 100% slow twitch.  Let's put this another way:  (and I'm just using random numbers here that are probably unrealistic, bear with me).  Let's say someone who is 80% fast twitch and 20% slow twitch has a baby with someone who is precisely the other way.  Would the child develop more of the fast twitch or more of the slow twitch?